# obtener un access token con laravel

Tags: tokens

Tengo un problema para obtener los access token para mi api con laravel. Sigo los pasos que me dicen pero cuando lo solicito, mediante postman, la respuesta es que no es válido. Utilizo un grant_type, client_id, client_secret y un usuario que existe.
¿Alguna pista para empezar?

Comment: a que servicio estas intentando pedir dicho token? por favor, revisa tu consulta e indica las pruebas que has hecho hasta ahora. Asi de momento te diria que te asegures que postman esta en "POST" (aunque eso ya lo tendras...)

Comment: Route::post('oauth/token','\Laravel\Passport\Http\Controllers\AccessTokenController@issueToken');